# How to display a div while another div is hovered with position: fixed?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

I have three divs, one hidden:

- Parent

  - Message (hidden)
  - Image

I need to display *Message* when *Image* is hovered. That's usually a simple job, but I think the problem arises at the positioning of the divs.

I have an image at the upper right corner, and a text message should appear right next to it (to it's left, actually) when the image is hovered. Parent is a `100% x 32px` bar, with `position: fixed`, so the icon *and* the message float around the whole page.

I've already tried plenty answers at SO. The only one that worked was using `#parent:hover > div`, but that makes the message show anytime the cursor hovers *Parent*, which is bad as *Parent* is a big invisible bar on the top of the page (should work well with shrinkwrapping, though, but I couldn't do it).

Here is [the js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rrnFK/) If you have any alternative approach please tell me.

**EDIT**: This is a example image of how it should work. It should also float and scroll with the page.
[image: example_img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the position of elements as mentioned in your style.

This is because you are using Adjascent Sibling selector `+`. “adjacent” means “immediately following,”

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdGqG/)

### css

```
#img:hover + #msg {
    display: block;
}
```

#Html Snippet

```
    <div id="img">
        <a href="some link here">
        <img src="http://j.mp/18xsrJQ"/>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div id="msg">
            This should appear if icon is hovered.
    </div>
```

To illustrate this:-

Consider this simple example :- To make the `p` immediately following the `h3` tag appear in gray color. If you put p before h3 it wont work. That is how the Adjacent sibling selector works.

```
<h3>Hey, an H3 element</h3>
<p>Here's a paragraph which is short</p>

 h3 +p {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the selector. However I get again that annoying behaviour that also happens with `#parent:hover > div`: when you hover the big *Parent* div it also shows the message. It should appear only when hovering *Image*.

Comment: Yes is your div that wide? You have contents in there?

Comment: No, I don't have content. That's why I think I'm not doing it the right way. Check the edit.